# Fixture file data undefine

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

Here is my fixture file and problem is when i trying to access preCreatedUser data its undefined for some reason -> file name pre-created-user.json

```
{
  "preCreatedUser": {
    "email": "test@test.app",
    "password": "password",
    "phone": "test",
    "documentId": "test",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "citizenship": "test",
    "dateOfBirth": "test",
    "address": "test"
  }
}
```

Here is where i am calling it, this works since other fixture files do give me data

before(() => cy.fixture('pre-created-user').then((u: User) => (preCreatedUser = u)));

Using it like that

```
console.log(preCreatedUser.email); //undefined here
LogInPage.logIn(preCreatedUser.email, preCreatedUser.password);
NavigationBar.profile();

    UserProfile.emailInputValue.then((c) => c.trim()).should('eq', preCreatedUser.email);
```

Comment: How are you using the value from your fixtures file ?

Comment: Are you getting the correct values for these `preCreatedUser.email` and `preCreatedUser.password`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one test block, then using `before` will work. If you have multiple tests, you have to use `beforeEach`.

You have to write the `before` block like this:

```js
before(function () {
  cy.fixture('pre-created-user.json').then((preCreatedUser: any) => {
    this.preCreatedUser = preCreatedUser
  })
})
```

Then in your test, you can do this:

```js
it('Test Case', function () {
  cy.then(() => {
    console.log(this.preCreatedUser.email)
  })
  //or
  cy.log(this.preCreatedUser.email)

  LogInPage.logIn(preCreatedUser.email, preCreatedUser.password)
  NavigationBar.profile()

  UserProfile.emailInputValue
    .then((c) => c.trim())
    .should('eq', preCreatedUser.email)
})
```

From the cypress docs:

> If you store and access the fixture data using this test context
> object, make sure to use function () { ... } callbacks. Otherwise, the
> test engine will NOT have this pointing at the test context.